# Need to identify this pin receptacle and plug

Tags: identification, pins, plug

I need to identify this pin and this plug so I can order more.

**RESEARCH**: I've pored over Molex.com, Allied Electronics, and here with no success. Please understand, I'm fairly new to electrical engineering and specifically these components. I'm not even sure what to call them. If I knew, it would make finding them a lot easier. I want to know, and I want to do this correctly, and that's why I'm here.

**PIN**: Critically, unlike nearly every other pin (female pin? pin receptacle?) I can find, this one is seated using the large notch closest to the end. Most I've found use opposing winglets that jut out to secure them within the plug housing, and that won't work here.

**PLUG**: The current plug has 12 ports in a rectangle layout. The new plugs need to have 4 ports in a square layout. As such, I destroyed one of the unneeded pins to see how it worked, thinking worst-case I can just cut these down to size. Note the style of the clip that secures the whole plug, as well as the small movable arm that holds the pin receptacle in place.

I need these parts to fix my car. It's parked until I figure this out. Also, I'd love to know the proper names for all of these components. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Photos attached.

**EDIT:** This is going into a headlight ballast on an Audi. It was produced in 2001. Make and model won't help because these aftermarket headlights don't share any internal wiring with their OEM counterparts. The factory ballast was a 12-pin, and that style has been phased out, so now I need a 4-pin plug.

The original 12-pin plug bears the marking **L JST**. The pins are 1/2" long with a 1/16" opening.

Tons of photos of the pin, plug, and ballast here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLgBR.jpg

**EDIT 2:** The "socket contact" as it's called appears to be [SSF-21T-P1.4](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/SSF-21T-P1.4/455-1563-1-ND/773782) from JST. That locking mechanism is called a **housing lance**. Still looking for the connector plug itself, which appears to have come from the [JST HL series,](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eHL2.pdf) which should work but the plug on the new ballast features two raised shafts on sockets 2 and 4 - see the imgur pics.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another picture or two of the housing from different angles might help us identify the part more easily.  Also, some dimensions or perhaps a ruler in the picture for scale would help.

Comment: any part numbers stamped on the connector shell?

Comment: is it like this? ... http://imgmgr.banggood.com/images/upload/2015/08/SKU263964/c%20(9).jpg

Comment: I can't really tell without more pictures. Can you post one of the housing from a different (oblique) angle? If you can only attach two images, feel free to link to a picture and someone with more rep can edit it into your question...

Comment: Justin - Welcome :-) FYI these are the current [Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines). As already commented, more photos (especially on the connector "faces") are needed. Also, your title says: "*Need to identify this Molex pin receptacle and plug*". How do you know this is a connector made by Molex, and not one of the other multi-pin latching connector manufacturers? If you have specific information that this connector was made by Molex, please edit the question and add that info.

Comment: https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Molex/172258-1012?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs%252bGHln7q6pmwYxG2U8F7X0OwECbTvEuaktnCpl20MQ8w%3d%3d

Comment: what is the connector from? .... you said car .... if I wanted to have the best chance of identifying a connector, I would provide make, model, year of manufacture, location of connector, what it is connected to, picture of both of the connectors face on and side and back, any numbers or marks printed on the connectors, the exact dimensions of the connector (distance between centers of pins)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help so far.

@jsotola those are similar but not exact. The latch style isn't correct on either one.

Adding more photos momentarily.

Comment: Photos and measurements have been added to the original post.

Comment: If you say model and year won’t help, which I think is incorrect, try a scrapyard and find a similar car to scavenge the parts from...

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but these aftermarket headlights were limited production and don't share any internal wiring with the OEM headlights.

Comment: While this was an interesting puzzle to research, it's arguably a shopping question and seems to have been abandoned.  Voting to close so the harass-the-community daemon doesn't keep dredging it back up.

Answer (score 0):

If the spacing between contact is 3.96 mm these are likely JST SL or HL or similar.

SL http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSL.pdf

HL http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eHL2.pdf

- The little raised feature just beyond the slot matches
- SL/HL have a 1.4mm wide flattened blade - that's 1/18 inch which compares nicely to the observed 1/16 inch
- the "L JST" reportedly seen on one hints at it, too.

If the dimensions are wrong they might have re-used the idea at a different size.

Comment: That's one answer down! SSF-21T-P1.4 appears to be the correct socket contact.

Can't spot the difference between SSF-21T-P1.4 and SSF-01T-P1.4, but critically the slot for the housing lance (locking mechanism) is there on both.

As for the connector, it appears to be from the HL series (perhaps it's an older design, since this part is from ~2001). The new connector receptacle (what I'm plugging into on the ballast) seems to accept a style with the same locking tab as the HL but with notable raised shafts on slots 2 and 4 (if I'm reading this correctly - the photos show this better).

Comment: note: the HL connector comes in 12 contact version ......  the SL version does not